# Ordenar columna según criterio

Tags: python, pandas, ordenamiento

necesito ordenar un df de mas de 500 filas según la columna distName, tengo el siguiente ejemplo para ayudar a entender el problema.

```
 import pandas as pd

  df = pd.DataFrame({'distName': ['PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-24','PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-21',                          
 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-23','PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-3',
 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-15','PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-13',
 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-16','PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-14',
 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-22','PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-2',
 'PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-1','PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-0'],
           'points': ['25', '15', '15', '14', '20', '20', '25', '29','1','5','3','5']})
               
ver = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Intente realizando lo siguiente  sin resultado

```
  ver = ver.sort_values(by=['distName'], ascending = (True))
```

Necesito obtener ordenado de este modo:

```
                 distName                          points
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-0          5
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-1          3
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-2          5
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-3          14
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-13         20
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-14         29
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-15         20
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-16         25
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-21         15
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-22         1
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-23         15
PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-945971/LNBTS-945971/LNMME-24         25
```

desde ya gracias, saludos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para nuestra suerte pandas también da la opción de proporcionar un parámetro `key` para realizar la ordenación en base a algún criterio o característica. Por lo visto tu quieres ordenar en base al último numero que se muestra en cada valor de la columna, por eso con ayuda de un `split` separaremos los datos, escogeremos el último y lo convertiremos en entero ya que si lo dejamos como string entonces no obtendremos el resultado esperado. La sentencia quedaría así.

```py
ver.sort_values(by=['distName'], 
                ascending =True, 
                key=lambda col: [int(i.split("-")[-1]) for i in col])
```

Comment: excelente gracias @Christian

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que necesitas un orden múltiple, por un lado la parte alfanumérica de `distName` y por el otro la numérica, representada por los últimos números. A mi criterio lo más simple es (1) "dividir" la columna en dos partes (2) convertir la segunda parte en un valor numérico (3) ordenar ahora sí por estas dos columnas.

```
ver['s'] = ver['distName'].str.extract('(.*)-\d+$').astype(str)
ver['n'] = ver['distName'].str.extract('.*-(\d+)$').astype(int)
ver = ver.sort_values(by=['s', 'n'], ascending = True).drop(['s', 'n'], axis=1)
```

Básicamente usamos unos patrones regulares con `extract()` para dividir la columna origen en dos nuevas con el tipo de dato apropiado y luego simplemente ordenamos, y eliminamos finalmente las columnas agregadas.

Comment: por lo que yo veo todas las filas de la columna `distname` tienen la misma cadena y solo varía el ultimo número lo que deja totalmente innecesario el tener que dividir la cadena

Comment: @Christian, yo preferí dar una solución más robusta.